# Ubuntu 14.04 Ethernet Connectivity Issue on startup

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system. My problem is when I start the system after previously shutting it down properly, my system cannot connect to the network via Ethernet connection. Even after searching through number of forums, I am not able to solve the issue.

When I fire ifconfig in terminal, it gives me following output:

> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:12518 (12.5 KB)  TX bytes:12518 (12.5 KB)

Now the strange thing is if I restart the system, it connects to the network and I am able to access the Internet.

After starting the system, when I hit ifconfig in the terminal, it gives me following output:

> eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:72:b9:26:97:83
>             inet addr:192.168.1.115  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::4e72:b9ff:fe26:9783/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:76 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:6091 (6.0 KB)  TX bytes:11017 (11.0 KB)
>             Interrupt:20 Memory:fe400000-fe420000
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:12518 (12.5 KB)  TX bytes:12518 (12.5 KB)

Please let me know any idea which would be helpful to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: You get ip by dhcp or static ip?
Can you make static ip? and in config file /etc/network/interfaces add line: > auto eth1